# How to get "onTouchEnd" event in Android?

Tags: java, android, touch

What is the name of a event that is called once he user stops touching the screen for the View object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onTouchEvent fires with a type of ACTION_UP.

Answer (score 1):

You can check here to see all available events: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP

The one for you is ACTION_UP.

Hope this helps!

Update:

Moreover when you move outside the View without moving up your finger, ACTION_CANCEL is called. So you should handle both.